# How to increase the speed of compile time of Cordova run

Tags: cordova

Does any one know how to decrease the time for cordova run as it take a decent 1 and a half minutes

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Cordova `prepare` has been optimized recently using incremental approach, see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11117
So this feature will be out with corresponding platforms releases.